# инициализация объекта в python

Tags: python

Есть такой код создания класса без `__init__`:

```
class Person:
    def setName(self, n, s):
        self.name = n
        self.surname = s
p1.setName("Bill", "Ross")
>>> p1.name, p1.surname
('Bill', 'Ross')
```

И такой с инициализацией:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, n, s):
        self.name = n
        self.surname = s

p1 = Person("Sam", "Baker")
print(p1.name, p1.surname)
```

Я сколько не читаю не могу понять когда нужно использовать `__init__`, а когда нет. Объясните вкратце пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В первом случае, Вы можете создать объект класса `Person` с пустыми полями, и уже потом присвоить им значения с помощью функции `setName`:

```
p1 = Person()
p1.setName("Bill", "Ross")
```

Во втором случае в описании класса `Person` используется конструктор класса `__init__`. Таким образом при создании объекта класса необходимо сразу передать ему параметры.

```
p1 = Person("Bill", "Ross")
```

Если попытаться создать объект без указания полей, то получите сообщение об ошибке:

```
p1 = Person()
# TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'n' and 's'
```

Таким образом конструктор необходим, если Вы хотите, чтобы при создании объекта ему сразу были установлены некоторые параметры.

В какой-то степени это вопрос удобства, оба варианта правильны, но, если Вы хотите создать несколько объектов, например, того же класса `Person`, то так:

```
p1 = Person("Bill", "Ross")
p2 = Person("John", "Smith")
p3 = Person("Paul", "Jones")
```

выглядит лаконичнее, чем

```
p1 = Person()
p1.setName("Bill", "Ross")
p2 = Person()
p2.setName("John", "Smith")
p3 = Person()
p3.setName("Paul", "Jones")
```

Comment: я все понял, спасибо Вам!